# Can not delete/rename file in NetBeans after Git init

Tags: git, netbeans

I am using NetBeans and after `git init` and `git add .` when I try delete/rename/copy file in project recieve Warning:

- Git failed to copy /var/www/(...) java.io.IOExeprion. Acces acces deny
- Git failed to move /var/www/(...) java.io.IOExeprion. Acces acces deny
- Cannot delete file file_name

What is wrong? I'd like to mentioned that in anoder projects this problem not exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that used folders has a insufficient privileges. Try `chmod -R 777` for /var/www/your_project folder.

Comment: Holy crap ! Previously I set privileges for all subdirectiories but didnt think about main folder. Thanks a lot mate !